# How can I solve this memory leak? Actually, where is the memory leak?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks

I would like to create an easy todo appliacation, that stores data in shared preferences. Therefore I have created a class called PrefManager, which one contains all of my methods in connection managing preferences. In this case the method "getSharedPreferences" needs a context. Thats okay, but I have to use this class all in my other classes, included the recyclerView adapter class.

So i made this "solution" (ToDoActivity):

```
public static PrefManager mPrefManager;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    adapter = new ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter(this);
    mPrefManager = new PrefManager(context, adapter);
    mPrefManager.setupThePreferences();
    ...
```

and imported everywhere:

```
   import static bla.bla.bla.ToDoActivity.mPrefManager;
```

But I get this error:

Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to PrefManager which has field context pointing to Context); this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run). A static field will leak contexts.

How can I make it better? How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

I use it for example in the RecycleView Adapter by deleting an item:

```
 public class ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

There:

```
holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

         int identifier = holder.myTodo.getIdentifier();
         removeTodo(position);
         mPrefManager.deleteThePref(identifier);

         return false;
    }
});
```

Or in my Todo creating activity:

```
public class CreateActivity extends Activity
```

There:

```
btnCreateExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mPrefManager.saveNewToDo(editTodoTitle.getText().toString(), spinnerTodoPriority.getSelectedItemPosition(), editTodoDescription.getText().toString(), date);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest you do not pass the `adapter` to `PrefManager`.It's more like a tool for you to save data and get data. And the tool can be get from everywhere `instanseof` context.

Comment: Could you please explain it? I am just learning this. :)

Comment: Where do you want `PrefManager `?Activity or something ?Show the `PrefManager ` if possible.

Comment: Edited. I added some examples.

Comment: I think you should not use like this `public static PrefManager mPrefManager;`. Because thhis static object will hold the context(from adapter) and GC can not recycle the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In `TodoActivity`,declare PrefManager and generate `getter` for it.

  ```
  private PrefManager mPrefManager;
  public PrefManager getmPrefManager{
      return mPrefManager;
  }
  ```
- In `Adapter` ,when you delete an item:

  ```
   removeTodo(position);
   ((TodoActivity)context).getmPreManager().deleteThePref(identifier);
  ```
- Recreate constructor for `PrefManager` and pass only `context`:

  ```
  public PrefManager(Context context){
       super();
       context.getSharedPreferences(...);
  }
  ```
- In `CreateActivity`, new a `PrefManager`:

  ```
  mPrefManager = new PrefManager(context);
  mPrefManager.setupThePreferences();
  ```

Comment: God bless you, its working :) But i have one more dummy question: When I  am passing only a `context`, how do i get an `adapter`? (Because its a whole new object, isnt it?) Or its working just because the method `setupThePreferences()` doesnt use the `adapter`?

Comment: Where do you want the adapter? Usually the current adapter can only be got from the current Activity.

Answer (score -4):

Try extending your activities to access your ToDoActivity.

For example:

```
public class AnotherActivity extends ToDoActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);

context = getApplicationContext();
adapter = new ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter(this);
mPrefManager = new PrefManager(context, adapter);
mPrefManager.setupThePreferences();
...
    }
}
```